# What does $0 represent in closures in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, closures

I have seen closures in Swift use `$0` internally and sometimes they use `$1`. What exactly is `$0` and what are other `$X` can you use?

Here are examples of it in use:

```
applyMutliplication(2, {$0 * 3})
array.map({$0 + 1})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What does $0 and $1 mean in Swift Closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144322/what-does-0-and-1-mean-in-swift-closures)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a shorthand argument name.

From the Swift Book:

> “Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline
>   closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s
>   arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.”
>
> — Apple Inc. [“The Swift Programming Language.”](https://itun.es/ca/jEUH0.l)

It helps reduce the verbosity of your code (sometimes at the cost of readability), so you don't have to write out long argument lists when defining closures.

Comment: Because verbosity can provide understandability.

Comment: Yea, you are right, sometimes verbostiy does help readability and understandability, though that starts to border into opinion.  Either way I updated my answer.

Comment: Nice change. Reducing the writing out of long argument lists is not the end goal, that happens only one and there is auto-completion to help. The end goal should be readability since the code will generally be read many times.

Comment: While there are no argument in the closure, what will be $0 referred to?(The caller self?)

Comment: ok.. but what if I need to use closure inside closure? if I reffer again to $0 will it think of .. as the same variable? example : TransformOf<[Int], [String]>(fromJSON: {$0!.map($0!.toInt())}, toJSON: {$0!.map("\(($0))")})..... i need this function to take the first "fromJSON" closure a [String] and transform it to [Int] and the second closure do the reversed stuff.. but it will never compile nor it will compile if I do ... TransformOf<[Int], [String]>(fromJSON: {($0! as [String]).map($0!.toInt())}, toJSON: {($0! as [Int]).map("\(($0))")}).. Please advice