# Checking if an array of custom objects contain a specific custom object

Tags: swift

say i have a very simple `Person` class

```
class Person {
    var name:String
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

and i wish to store a collections of such `Person`s in a property, which is an array with type Person, of a People class

```
class People {
    var list:[Person] = []
}
```

perhaps i achieve this as follows

```
var alex = Person(name:"Alex")
var people = People()
people.list.append(alex)
```

QUESTION: how do i check if people.list contains the instance alex, please?

my simple attempt, which i was hoping to return `true`

```
people.list.contains(alex)
```

calls an error `"cannot convert value of type 'Person' to expected argument type '@noescape (Person) throws -> Bool'"`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are two `contains` functions:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Return `true` iff `element` is in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}

extension SequenceType {
    /// Return `true` iff an element in `self` satisfies `predicate`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
}
```

The compiler is complaining because the compiler knows that `Person` is not `Equatable` and thus `contains` needs to have a `predicate` but `alex` is not a predicate.

If the people in your array are `Equatable` (they aren't) then you could use:

```
person.list.contains(alex)
```

Since they aren't equatable, you could use the second `contains` function with:

```
person.list.contains { $0.name == alex.name }
```

or, as Martin R points out, based on 'identity' with:

```
person.list.contains { $0 === alex }
```

or you could make `Person` be `Equatable` (based on either `name` or identity).

Comment: many thanks - and to @Martin R: "theperson.list.contains { $0 === alex }" worked a charm :-)

Comment: in case anyone is wondering what "$0" stands for -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491620/what-does-0-represent-in-closures-in-swift

Answer (score 24):

> QUESTION: how do i check if people.list contains the instance alex, please?

`class Person` is a *reference type*, and `var alex` is a reference
to the object storage. The *identical-to* operator `===`
checks if two constants or variables refer to the same instance
of a class.

Therefore, in order to check if the list contains a
 *specific instance,* use  the predicate-based `contains()`
method, and compare instances with  `===`:

```
if people.list.contains({ $0 === alex }) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How can we get index where condition becomes true?

Comment: This is really very useful answer.