# How to search specific element from generic array e.g [AnyObject] in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to search whether GENERIC array contains specific element or not in swift.

```
    var arrProducts = [AnyObject]()

    arrProducts.append(Article())
    arrProducts.append(Flower())
    arrProducts.append(Chocolate())
```

Here products can be any custom object which I am adding in this array.

Now I want to check if arrProducts contain any of 3 custom class objects

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679486/shorthand-to-test-if-an-object-exists-in-an-array-for-swift ? Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34504697/1187415 ?

Comment: @MartinR I have updated my question for more clarification.

Comment: `if arrProducts.contains({$0 === myArticle})` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34504697/1187415 ?

Comment: What about giving a common interface?

Answer (score 0):

This will check "if arrProducts contain any of 3 custom class objects".

```
let isContainingAnyOf3CustomClassObject =
    arrProducts.contains {$0 is Article || $0 is Flower || $0 is Chocolate}
//->true
```

---

If you need to retrieve all elements of any 3 types, you can use `filter`.

```
let elementsOfAny3Types = arrProducts.filter {$0 is Article || $0 is Flower || $0 is Chocolate}
```

If you want the first element, you can use `first`.

```
let firstElementOfAny3Types = arrProducts.filter {$0 is Article || $0 is Flower || $0 is Chocolate}.first
```

But this may be more efficient:

```
if let firstMatchingIndex = arrProducts.indexOf({$0 is Article || $0 is Flower || $0 is Chocolate}) {
    let firstMatchingElement = arrProducts[firstMatchingIndex]
    print(firstMatchingElement)
}
```

If any above are not what you mean, you need to modify your question and describe what you really want to achieve more precisely.

Comment: Need to search specific element from array which could be of any 3 types!

Comment: Checking contains or not and searching the exact element are different things and you'd better clarify such sort of things in your question. I'll update my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

One more method to search for objects of a specific class is `flatMap`. The benefit of this apporach is that you get an array with the right type.

### You have this

```
class Article { }
class Flower { }
class Chocolate { }

let products : [AnyObject] = [Article(), Flower(), Chocolate()]
```

### Let's extract the flowers

```
let flowers = products.flatMap { $0 as? Flower }
```

The `flowers` array has the following type `[Flower]` and contains only the right objects.