# Swift Add and Remove Item into array based on UITableview cell select and deselect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my case, I am loading `JSON` data into `Tableview` with help of `codable`. The tableview multiple `select` and `deselect` checkmark options available. Now, I need to `Insert` selected values into one `array` and same time if user deselect the cell need to `remove` relevant value from same array. The stored array data, I am going to use in multiple `viewcontroller`. How to achieve this?

**JSON Codable**

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let userid, firstname, designation: String?
    let profileimage: String?
}
```

**My Codebase for Tableview Delegate**

```
var studentsData = [Datum]()
var sessionData = [Datum]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.studentsData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
        let item = self.studentsData[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameCellLabel.text = item.firstname
        cell.subtitleCellLabel.text = item.designation
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let item = self.studentsData[indexPath.row]
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
                // UnCheckmark cell JSON data Remove from array
                if let index = sessionData.index(of:item) {
                    sessionData.remove(at: index)
                }
                print(sessionData)

            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                // Checkmark selected data Insert into array
                self.sessionData.append(item)
                print(sessionData)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By using the below code you can search the particular in the array and remove it easily.

if let index = selectedArr.firstIndex(of: item) {
                selectedArr.remove(at: index)
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the item inside the array by searching for its index

```
let index = try? array.firstIndex(where: { $0. userid == sessionData[indexPath.row].userid })
```

Or you can use this [Checking if an array of custom objects contain a specific custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503819/1369143)

Comment: but I am using searching, so for searching I used filteredarray. Thats the reason I used item variable. anyway I will try and update you here. Thank you so much for your reply :)