# What is $0 in Swift Array filters?

Tags: arrays, swift

Array filters in Swift use $0, what does it mean? What are other possible variations? Check array filter example in [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter).

Comment: So in the case of `filter`, `$0` is an element of the sequence.

Comment: you can check more detail answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34785745/4601170