# Swift 4.2 weird -.map- behavior

Tags: swift, collections

I am having some trouble using .map on a collection in Swift 4.2.
Here is what is happening:

I have a property declared like this:

```
var cbPerifList:[CBPeripheral]!
```

Later in the code when I write:

```
_ = cbPerifList.map { (perif) -> Void in
    print(perif.identifier)
}
```

The compiler seems happy and does not complain.

But when I write:

```
_ = cbPerifList.map { (perif) -> Void in
    print(perif.identifier)
    print("HELLO")
}
```

The compiler complains by displaying this message.

```
Value of type '[CBPeripheral]' has no member 'identifier'
```

on the line of code: *print(perif.identifier)*

Can someone explain what is going on here?

1. I don't see why adding this line of code makes a difference.

   print("HELLO")
2. I expect perif to be of type CBPeripheral and not [CBPeripheral] as the error message says.

Comment: You should better use `forEach` instead of `map` here.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on playground (Xcode 10.1), both code snippets work. In addition, if you are aiming to just print the identifiers, you should do it via `for-in` or `forEach`, there is no reason to map the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `map` works in Swift (and elsewhere) is that it can map (change) input from one type to another. So in your case, you will call `map` on your `[CBPeripheral]` and for each element, the `map` function will return another value. So, if the `identifier` is a `String`, you will end out with an array of Strings.

That is how it should work.

However :)

In your case, you have defined your mapping function like so

```
(perif) -> Void
```

Meaning that you will run through your array and call map, with a function that returns nothing. Meaning that the outcome will be an array filled with Void values.

Therefore, as others are suggesting in the comments, if you just want to examine the content of your `cbPerifList`, you are better of using a `for in` loop like so

```
for cbPerif in cbPerifList {
    print(cbPerif.identifier)
}
```

If however, you're interested in getting an array of the names of your `CBPeripherals` you can do something like this

```
let names = cbPerifList.map { $0.identifier }
```

A comment to the above: To read more about how we can end up just writing `{ $0.name }` have a look at the chapter about [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) in the Swift documentation, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785745/4063602)

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the other answer and in the comments, using `forEach` or `for ... in` would be the proper way of traversing through the array.

But to answer your question and to explain why those seemingly identical code snippets behave differently: That is caused by a combination of several facts:

- `[CBPeripheral]!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO), and since Swift 3 those are treated like a regular optional if possible. Compare

  - [SE-0054 Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md)
  - [Swift 3 incorrect string interpolation with implicitly unwrapped Optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537177/swift-3-incorrect-string-interpolation-with-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)
  - [Implicitly unwrapped optional assign in Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633481/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-assign-in-xcode-8)
- [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) has a [`map()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) method:

  ```
  func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
  ```
- The [bodies of multi-statement closures don't participate in type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213785/1187415).

In the “single-statement” closure

```
_ = cbPerifList.map { (perif) -> Void in
    print(perif.identifier)
}
```

the compiler tries to infer the closure type from the `print` expression, and in order to type check `perif.identifier`, the IUO `cbPerifList` must be unwrapped to an array.

In the “multi-statement” closure

```
_ = cbPerifList.map { (perif) -> Void in
    print(perif.identifier)
    print("HELLO")
}
```

the compiler does not try to infer the closure type from the context. Therefore `cbPerifList` is treated like a regular optional, and `map()` is the above-mentioned `Optional.map` method. Inside the closure, `perif` has the unwrapped type `[CBPeripheral]`. That is why `perif.identifier` does not compile with the error message

> Value of type '[CBPeripheral]' has no member 'identifier'

You can “help” the compiler with an explicit type annotation

```
_ = cbPerifList.map { (perif: CBPeripheral) -> Void in
    print(perif.identifier)
    print("HELLO")
}
```

but – as already said – in this particular case there are better solutions.